# IIS 7.5 Max Concurrent requests per system

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, asp.net-mvc-file-upload

I hosted an ASP.NET MVC5 web application on a windows server 2008 R2 SP1.
in this website there is a upload file section which users can upload large files with max size of 1 GB. When they click on upload button another popup window will be opened to allow users do other things during files are being uploaded. I used [MvcFileUploader](https://github.com/marufbd/MvcFileUploader) for upload. The problem is while upload process is working, they can't open other pages from the site. I have tested theses items when files are uploading:

1. Users can open other websites ( result is uploader isn't using the
   whole available network traffic)
2. While a user is uploading, other users from another system can open our website easily (result is IIS server is working and isn't not responding)

So I came up with this conclusion that somewhere should be a restriction for max concurrent connection from each IP/system. Am I right?
do you have any suggestions?
I have already changed MvcFileUploader default configuration with these:

```
limitConcurrentUploads: 1,
sequentialUploads: true,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved uploader process to a new application which won't keep the main site's process busy.